# how to delete all files from a directory structure in a HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, recursion, hdfs

I am looking to clean up the environment. I want to execute the following command recursively, witout hard coding for each sub folder. As I have hundreds of subfolder in a HDFS directory.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /a/b1/c1/d1.txt

hadoop fs -rm -r /a/b2/c2/d2.txt

hadoop fs -rm -r /a/b3/c3/d3.txt

hadoop fs -rm -r /a/bn/cn/dn.txt
```

I want to delete all the *files* but not the directory or the sub-directories. I am not sure how to use a recursive command to keep the directory structure in HDFS while delete all the files in it.

Comment: You can't keep the directories from the command line, you need to iterate the directories in a script (Java would be easiest)

Comment: So I am using Talend big data tool so I can use java but not sure about the logic.

Comment: On a high level, import the `FileSystem` object from Hadoop, then iterate over folders and delete(path, false) on them... but make sure the directories are kept https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#delete(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /directory/structure/ | grep "\.json" | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -I{} hadoop fs -rm "{}"
```